# Big Sur-style sidebar Mac Catalyst in SwiftUI 2

Tags: swiftui, catalyst

I have problem with making sidebar look transparent. All advices about implementing it (even official Apple Documentation) is on AppDelegate/SceneDelegate. But since last update projects have only this file:
'''

```
 import SwiftUI
 import UIKit

 @main
 struct SpenTApp: App {


var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        NavigationView {
                        
                        SideBarView()
                            .background(Color.clear)
                            
                        DetailView()
                          
                    }
        
        .navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle())
            
    }
    
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Catalyst apps have some weird limitations, so to do what you want: SideBarView must be a List with `listStyle(SidebarListStyle())`.